# Wifi suddenly stopped working in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless, atheros

I am using ubuntu 14.04 lts.

Recently i faced a problem with my wifi, it is not working properly.Initially it was dropping connection frequently and now i cannot see wifi enabled button at all only networking enabled is there.

I also ran a script which create log of network related things, here it is the link to that log
http://paste.ubuntu.com/20148185/

can someone please solve myproblem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to upgrade kernel to 4.4. by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Reboot after the upgrade.